# c# remove empty null when using string.join in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I know that we can use the below to remove null or empty array when using string.join:

```
var res = string.Join(",", array.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

I've tried this in .Net 2.0 but can't. Sorry to declare but i have to use .net 2.0 for my application.
Is there any way for .net 2.0?

Comment: you can easily re-write the code to do what you want. .NET 2.0 does NOT support LINQ expressions. The code is basically finding items in the array where the current item is not null or empty and then finally joining the array together.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the null object in the array and Join them together afterwords?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a possible solution:

```
var nonNullItems = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in array) {
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        nonNullItems.Add(item);
}
var res = string.Join(",",nonNullItems.ToArray());
```

Comment: `ToArray` without LINQ?

Comment: Yes, `ToArray()` has been there all the time.

Comment: ... so it has. Carry on.

Comment: `List` has its own `ToArray()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You might have to replace `var` with `string` though, since the keyword was added in C# 3.0. But I believe current versions of Visual Studio compile correctly even if targeting the 2.0 framework,

Comment: @Greg Please see my comment to Zohar Peled's answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ugly hack like join/split/join:

```
string res = string.Join(",", 
             (string.Join(",", array).split(",", 
              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: `var` keyword is a compiler feature, not a .NET feature. It will work with whatever framework version you use, provided that you use a modern enough compiler/Visual Studio.

Comment: @Konamiman Thanks, I didn't know that. Edited my answer to remove that note.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array:

```
var tmp = new List<string>();

foreach(var s in array) 
{
    if (!string.IsNullNorEmpty(s)) tmp.Add(s);
}

var res = string.Join(",", tmp.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to (sort of) roll your own and needed this in more than one place in your project, you could roll your own "LINQ extensions" (obviously not extension methods since you're targeting .NET 2.0), but...

An important note:

- Unlike the LINQ `Where()`, this greedily evaluates the given collection, so if it's given an `IEnumerable` that doesn't end, this would cause an infinite loop.

Static method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T t);

    public static T[] Where<T>(IEnumerable<T> e, Func<T, bool> func) {
        IList<T> result = new List<T>();
        foreach (T each in e) {
            if (func(each)) {
                result.Add(each);
            }
        }
        T[] returnValue = new T[result.Count];
        result.CopyTo(returnValue, 0);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

and use:

```
string[] array = {"a", "b"};
string res = string.Join(
    ",", 
    EnumerableExtensions.Where(array, delegate(string s) { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s); })
);
```

Comment: As far as I know in and out-Types (variance and co-variance) are not possible on .NET 2.0 nor is the LAMBDA-Syntax enabled.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I targeted 2.0 when writing this.

Comment: Indeed, it worked for C# 3.0 upwards which however won´t necessarily apply to .NET 2.0

Comment: @HimBromBeere Here we go, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx - "In C#, variance is supported in the following scenarios: --- Covariance and contravariance in delegates, also known as “method group variance” (since C# 2.0) " - You are correct on the *syntax* issue however

Comment: I tried it out using the ISO-2 spec and id did not compile. However your link also states the following: `Variance for generic type parameters in interfaces and delegates (since C# 4.0)`. Anyway you updated your answer accordingly.

Comment: Indeed - you have all valid points regardless. It's a poor assumption on my part to assume they are targeting .NET 2.0 but using anything greater than C# 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I'm not sure about the performance.

```
string res = string.Join(",", Array.FindAll(array, delegate(string s) 
{ 
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s); 
} ));
```